# Lightbox2 Image numbers are not right! Always show the last image number only

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

For creating the Image slideshow with lightbox I am using Lightbox2 from 
"http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/"

Please find the code details from the URL above.

I'm having an issue now, when I have same image being shown number of times.
and then when you click on any of those repeated images to open in lightbox, it shows the last image's no.

Please see the image below:[image]

In this case, I clicked on the 1st image to open, but at bottom its showing "Image 4 of 4"

The same issue I also found being logged over here : https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/90, but no solution.

Please find my HTML code attached below:

```
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <p> <a id="pickheadImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="Pickhead" href="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg"> <img alt="0" id="pickheadImage" src="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg" width="200" height="150"> </a> </p>
    <p> <strong>Pickhead:</strong><br>
      <span id="pickheadImageDetails">Camera Not Found</span> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> <a id="pickheadImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="Processing Station Side" href="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg"> <img alt="1" id="pickheadImage" src="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg" width="200" height="150"> </a> </p>
    <p> <strong>Processing Station Side:</strong><br>
      <span id="pickheadImageDetails">Camera Not Found</span> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> <a id="pickheadImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="Processing Station Top" href="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg"> <img alt="2" id="pickheadImage" src="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg" width="200" height="150"> </a> </p>
    <p> <strong>Processing Station Top:</strong><br>
      <span id="pickheadImageDetails">Camera Not Found</span> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> <a id="pickheadImageLightBox" data-lightbox="image-1" title="Card Scan" href="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg"> <img alt="3" id="pickheadImage" src="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg" width="200" height="150"> </a> </p>
    <p> <strong>Card Scan:</strong><br>
      <span id="pickheadImageDetails">Camera Not Found</span> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

All Scripts can be found from the URL"http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/"

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely that your problem is that your `id`s are not unique (they should be).

Try adding a counter or something similar, so you have `pickheadImageLighbox-1` and so on. Same goes for all `id`s on the page. If you want to use the same string over and over, to group them, you should be using `class` instead of `id`.